# How would you test for ppm of lead in a powder?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Looking to test the ppm for lead in a powder that is a food item.
No experience in chemistry.
Possibly may need to test for other heavy metals.

Comment: Can you add more context? What instruments you have access to?

Comment: I have zero instruments but could purchase some basics from a surplus store. I don't have great access to a workspace...

Comment: No the instruments for detect metals in food will cost a fortune. You need to contact a professional lab.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! [Here are EPA-recommended kits and vendor contact information](https://www.epa.gov/lead/lead-test-kits).

Google is your friend. You are in Canada, so I'm uncertain if your regular pharmacies carry such kits (many of ours do in the US).

Start with home kits - they have you mail-in a specimen - and graduate if needed based on LDL (lower detection limits).

You should be able to get a good idea (maybe binary) about contaminants, which you can then follow-up with more expensive but very worthwhile tests involving more advanced analytical techniques.

Comment: The article you linked is titled "Lead Test Kit Buying Guide," but it doesn't recommend or link any products. It's just very general info about conducting at-home lead testing, mostly on paint.

Comment: @SusieDerkins - Good point, edited to include the EPA recommended products which contain links to the vendors.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like these kits are only for paint though.

Comment: @SusieDerkins - What exactly are you interested in testing? These tests are general in the sense that a powdered (dry) substance can be used, regardless of source. Paint is the most common one. What is your intended use case and what have you found in your searches?

Comment: My use case is exactly the same as the OP's. I want to test a food substance that is a powder for lead content. I'm not aware of any documentation that says food samples can or should be run in paint test kits. My searches have only turned up kits for testing paint samples.

Comment: I'm assuming that dehydrating, grinding, and otherwise prepping the food sample are not on the table here; so you have a few options, first of which is a commercial lab with the requisite equipment and analytical procedures. The second, if the food has been ingested or you are concerned that someone has been consuming lead-containing food, is/are blood/urine tests which can be done via regular physicians. That said, the latter doesn't confirm from whence the lead came; but if you are willing to spend the money, that's definitive.